# Lighttpd 1.4.45 - HTTP to HTTPS redirects not replacing ${url.authority}${url.path}${qsa}

Tags: configuration, https, redirect, lighttpd

I tried to reconfigured my lighttpd to automatically relocate any HTTP requests to HTTPS requests. To do this, I found the following config snipped in the [Lighttpd Redmine Wiki](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/HowToRedirectHttpToHttps):

```
$HTTP["scheme"] == "http" {
            url.redirect = ("" => "https://${url.authority}${url.path}${qsa}")
}
```

However, lighttpd does not seem to replace the placeholders. Here is a sample HTTP-Request/Response via telnet (I replaced my Hostname with 'example.org', all the rest is original):

```
# telnet localhost 80
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: example.org

HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://${url.authority}${url.path}${qsa}
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Date: Fri, 11 Sep 2020 12:43:32 GMT
Server: lighttpd/1.4.45

Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Instead of `Location: https://${url.authority}${url.path}${qsa}` the line should be `Location: https://example.org/`.

What's wrong with it? Did I forget to load a module?

Any ideas?

### Some parts of my lighttpd.conf:

Since the loading order of modules seems to be important. Here is my current config for that:

```
server.modules = (
        "mod_expire",
        "mod_access",
        "mod_alias",
        "mod_compress",
        "mod_redirect",
        "mod_rewrite",
        "mod_setenv"
)
```

```
# cat /etc/debian_version
9.13
```

Lighttpd seems to be happy with the configuration file (there is no output for -t or -tt):

```
# lighttpd -tt -v -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf
lighttpd/1.4.45 (ssl) - a light and fast webserver
Build-Date: Jan 14 2017 21:07:19
#
```

Answer (score 2):

After some more research, I finally found the solution:

The named placeholders are only supported for lighttpd versions 1.4.50+, but for the older version there is a different solution:

```
$HTTP["scheme"] == "http" {
        $HTTP["host"] =~ ".*" {
                url.redirect = (".*" => "https://%0$0")
        }
}
```

This seems to work. `%0` is replaced by the full host name (result of last regex match) and `$0` is replaced by the whole URI including query string parts. This is exactly what I need...

Comment: lighttpd 1.4.45 is quite old.  I am guessing you are using Debian Stretch.  Please consider upgrading to lighttpd 1.4.53 in stretch-backports.

Comment: Yes! I'm using Debian Stretch... Looking at stretch-backports is a great idea! Thanks!